# CSS positioning 2 shifted columns

Tags: html, css

first of all is there a good tutorial about positioning elements which really explains what's going on? I've read multiple but can't get a grip on it.

the specific problem I have is as follows:

I have a header div-element (in red) with underneath 2 columns(white and green). Normally with float:left; i can position the elements next to each-other. But now I want one (the white one) to move a bit over the header als shown.

with relative positioning with a negative top value I can get the white one at the right position but how to position the second column. When adjusting the browser size it al gets messed up.

```
#Column1
{
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: -140px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  left: 70px;
  width: 280px;
  min-height: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#Column2
{
  float: left;   
  width: 800px;
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

[image: DIV positions graphically explained]

Comment: http://www.alistapart.com/topics/topic/css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3Xz6/9/) that demonstrates your layout without floats using position **absolute**.
In my experience position absolute is more flexible and made for this kind of layouts, especially when you want to *dock* elements using top, right, bottom and left.
There are circumstance where you need to fallback on using floats, but in this case it is not needed.

Use floats to float things around it and position absolute to dock things.

**The HTML**

```
<div id="Header">header</div>
<div id="Column1">Left</div>
<div id="Column2">Right</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
#Header {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}
#Column1 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  top: -140px; left: 70px;
  width: 280px;
  min-height: 500px;
}
#Column2 {
  position: absolute;   
  background-color: #00FF00;
  left: 350px; top: 200px; right: 0;
  min-height: 360px;
}​
```

**Update** Remove display:none from the **.more** class in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3Xz6/9/) and see that the containers are flexible as well.

Comment: Yeah I would agree that `position: absolute` is good for "docking" elements, but there are definitely better ways of going about it.

Comment: @Wex Sure! A CSS grid system is better. Why do you think floats are better than position absolute? Sure you can make it work with floats, but doesn't it feel a like a hack? Overflow: hidden :-)

Comment: `float` is generally better because it allows for content to dynamically resize (As opposed to using `position: absolute`, which always requires you to set specific positions for each element). `overflow: hidden` is certainly not a hack.

Comment: I know what overflow hidden does, but it isn't very semantic in my eyes? What does it tell you about my layout? That it is using floats? Or that it wants to 'hide' content.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just gonna spitball here:

HTML

```
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="white"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
```

CSS

```
#red {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f00;
}
#white {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-top: -40px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 400px;
}
#green {
    width: 76%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #0f0;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Does it work?

Comment: A couple unnecessary `float` and `position` declarations in there but not a bad way of doing it.

Comment: I tried to do it correctly the first time without testing it :-) I did, but you're right, it's not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a minus margin

http://jsfiddle.net/gAKAK/

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a complex request, so don't feel bad that you weren't able to figure it out. You shouldn't have to set the `width` of anything other than your sidebar for this solution; my solution relies on an uncommon use of `overflow: hidden` to achieve this.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/uBQEu/

HTML:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="white"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#header { 
    background: red;
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid #000; }
#white {
    background: #fff;
    float: left;
    margin: -30px 0 0 70px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 230px;
    border: 1px solid #000; }
#green { 
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden; 
    height: 201px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: 0;
    border-left: 0; }
```

Comment: A good article on why `overflow: hidden;` helps in this situation can be found here: http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/

Comment: Still doesn't tell me why floats are not a hack and the wrong tool in most cases. I have used floats to many times myself, before I realised that using position relative and absolute is so much easier in many cases. Even in flexible layouts.

Comment: I don't know why you keep referring to `float` as a hack. I guess it's just a matter of personal preference. Using `float` seems to have saved the trouble of adding an arbitrary container.